# Regular Expression to match process arguments

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net

I have this string:

```
Process.exe /Switch=Value /Switch="C:\Path with spaces\file.txt" wrong argument
```

I would like to capture these parts:

> ```
> · 1st Match: Process.exe
> · 2nd Match: /Switch=Value
> · 3rd Match: /Switch="C:\Path with spaces\file.txt"
> · 4th Match: wrong
> · 5th Match: argument
> ```

The regular expression need to be for generic use (a process with real arguments), not only be adapted for this case.

This is what Im trying:

```
Dim DebugArguments As String =
    "HotkeyMaker.exe /Hotkey=Escape /run=""c:\folder with spaces\notepad.exe"""

For Each match As Match In Regex.Matches(DebugArguments, "([^\s]+[^""])")
    MsgBox(match.Value)
Next match
```

Comment: You can't parse this until you layout rules for the argument breaks. Got any that you can think of?

Comment: Will there always be 5 and only five arguments?

Comment: @ridgerunner no, it's just an example, the amount of arguments is undefinied

Comment: @sin, sorry my english is not very good, what do you mean?, the syntax is similar to some Microsoft applications, for example the SC.exe command: `sc.exe config themes type="own"` but also with the `/` char.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**
Here you go, a regex to parse C/C++ command line arguments. Each argument needs to be
further sub-processed to resolve escapes and double quotes on the argument level.

Further, this does not parse special pipe/redirection symbols as first parsed by the command interpreter (cmd.exe). Instead this separates(parses) the string passed to the CreateProcess() for a language. This one is C/C++ and might be parsed differently, depending on the *language* invoked by the Command.

Reference used - http://www.daviddeley.com/autohotkey/parameters/parameters.htm#WINCRULESREPH

**Edit2** Added Command parse part

```
 # CmdLineParser_Cpp.rxf
 # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 # Reference used - "How Command Line Parameters Are Parsed" C/C++ cmdline parsing:
 # http://www.daviddeley.com/autohotkey/parameters/parameters.htm#WINCRULESREPH
 # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 #  (?:^[ \t]*((?>[^ \t"\r\n]+|"[^"]+(?:"|$))+)|(?!^)[ \t]+((?>[^ \t"\\\r\n]+|(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*"[^"\\\r\n]*(?:\\.[^"\\\r\n]*)*"{1,2}|(?:\\(?:\\\\)*")+|\\+(?!"))+)|([^ \t\r\n]))
 #  "(?:^[ \\t]*((?>[^ \\t\"\\r\\n]+|\"[^\"]+(?:\"|$))+)|(?!^)[ \\t]+((?>[^ \\t\"\\\\\\r\\n]+|(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\\\\\)*\"[^\"\\\\\\r\\n]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\\\r\\n]*)*\"{1,2}|(?:\\\\(?:\\\\\\\\)*\")+|\\\\+(?!\"))+)|([^ \\t\\r\\n]))"
 #  @"(?:^[ \t]*((?>[^ \t""\r\n]+|""[^""]+(?:""|$))+)|(?!^)[ \t]+((?>[^ \t""\\\r\n]+|(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*""[^""\\\r\n]*(?:\\.[^""\\\r\n]*)*""{1,2}|(?:\\(?:\\\\)*"")+|\\+(?!""))+)|([^ \t\r\n]))"

 (?:
      ^ [ \t]* 
      (                             # (1 start), Command
           (?>
                [^ \t"\r\n]+          
             |  
                " [^"]+ 
                (?: " | $ )
           )+
      )                             # (1 end)
   |  
      (?! ^ )
      [ \t]+                        # Delimeter
      (                             # (2 start), Argument
           (?>
                [^ \t"\\\r\n]+ 
             |  
                (?<! \\ )
                (?: \\ \\ )*
                " [^"\\\r\n]* (?: \\ . [^"\\\r\n]* )*  "{1,2}
             |  
                (?:
                     \\ (?: \\ \\ )*  " 
                )+
             |  
                \\+ (?! " )
           )+
      )                             # (2 end)
   |  
      ( [^ \t\r\n] )                # (3), Bad character
 )


 #   #use strict;
 #   #use warnings;
 #   
 #   my $string;
 #   
 #   while ($string = <DATA>)
 #   {
 #       chomp($string);
 #       next if (length($string) == 0);
 #   
 #       print "\nString To Parse:  '$string'\n";
 #   
 #       while ( $string =~ 
 #          m~(?:^[ \t]*((?>[^ \t"\r\n]+|"[^"]+(?:"|$))+)|(?!^)[ \t]+((?>[^ \t"\\\r\n]+|(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*"[^"\\\r\n]*(?:\\.[^"\\\r\n]*)*"{1,2}|(?:\\(?:\\\\)*")+|\\+(?!"))+)|([^ \t\r\n]))~xg
 #             )
 #       {
 #          print "command:          $1\n" if (defined $1);   
 #          print "argument:         $2\n" if (defined $2);   
 #          print "bad char:         $3\n" if (defined $3);   
 #       }
 #   }
 #   __DATA__
 #   F:\"Program Files"\Test\"H "A\runthis.exe -arg
 #   "Console Application Template.vshost.exe" /Switch1=Value1 /Switch2="Value2"
 # 
 #   run-A  /Switch=Value /Switch="C:\Path with spaces\file.txt" -arg
 #   run-B  Hotkey="Escape"
 #   run-C  Command="Dir /B "*.*"" Path=..\..\
 #   
 #   run-01 CallMeIshmael
 #   run-02 "Call Me Ishmael"
 #   run-03 Cal"l Me I"shmael
 #   run-04 CallMe\"Ishmael 
 #   run-05 "CallMe\"Ishmael"
 #   run-06 "Call Me Ishmael\\" 
 #   run-07 "CallMe\\\"Ishmael" 
 #   run-08 a\\\b
 #   run-09 "\"Call Me Ishmael\"" 
 #   run-10 "C:\TEST A\\" 
 #   run-11 "\"C:\TEST A\\\""
 #   run-12 "a b c"  d  e
 #   run-13 "ab\"c"  "\\"  d
 #   run-14 a\\\b d"e f"g h
 #   run-15 a\\\"b c d
 #   run-16 a\\\\"b c" d e
 #   run-17 "a b c""
 #   run-18 """CallMeIshmael"""  b  c
 #   run-19 """Call Me Ishmael"""
 #   run-20 """"Call Me Ishmael"" b c
 #   run-21 """CallMeIshmael"""
 #   run-22 """Call Me Ishmael"""
 #   run-23 \"CallMeIshmael\"
 #   run-24 """"Call me Ishmael""""
 #   run-25 """"Call Me Ishmael""
 #   run-26 "\"Call Me Ishmael\""
```

Output >>

```
 String To Parse:  ' F:\"Program Files"\Test\"H "A\runthis.exe -arg'
 command:          F:\"Program Files"\Test\"H "A\runthis.exe
 argument:         -arg

 String To Parse:  ' "Console Application Template.vshost.exe" /Switch1=Value1 /S
 witch2="Value2"'
 command:          "Console Application Template.vshost.exe"
 argument:         /Switch1=Value1
 argument:         /Switch2="Value2"

 String To Parse:  ' run-A  /Switch=Value /Switch="C:\Path with spaces\file.txt"
 -arg'
 command:          run-A
 argument:         /Switch=Value
 argument:         /Switch="C:\Path with spaces\file.txt"
 argument:         -arg

 String To Parse:  ' run-B  Hotkey="Escape"'
 command:          run-B
 argument:         Hotkey="Escape"

 String To Parse:  ' run-C  Command="Dir /B "*.*"" Path=..\..\'
 command:          run-C
 argument:         Command="Dir /B "*.*""
 argument:         Path=..\..\

 String To Parse:  ' '

 String To Parse:  ' run-01 CallMeIshmael'
 command:          run-01
 argument:         CallMeIshmael

 String To Parse:  ' run-02 "Call Me Ishmael"'
 command:          run-02
 argument:         "Call Me Ishmael"

 String To Parse:  ' run-03 Cal"l Me I"shmael'
 command:          run-03
 argument:         Cal"l Me I"shmael

 String To Parse:  ' run-04 CallMe\"Ishmael '
 command:          run-04
 argument:         CallMe\"Ishmael

 String To Parse:  ' run-05 "CallMe\"Ishmael"'
 command:          run-05
 argument:         "CallMe\"Ishmael"

 String To Parse:  ' run-06 "Call Me Ishmael\\" '
 command:          run-06
 argument:         "Call Me Ishmael\\"

 String To Parse:  ' run-07 "CallMe\\\"Ishmael" '
 command:          run-07
 argument:         "CallMe\\\"Ishmael"

 String To Parse:  ' run-08 a\\\b'
 command:          run-08
 argument:         a\\\b

 String To Parse:  ' run-09 "\"Call Me Ishmael\"" '
 command:          run-09
 argument:         "\"Call Me Ishmael\""

 String To Parse:  ' run-10 "C:\TEST A\\" '
 command:          run-10
 argument:         "C:\TEST A\\"

 String To Parse:  ' run-11 "\"C:\TEST A\\\""'
 command:          run-11
 argument:         "\"C:\TEST A\\\""

 String To Parse:  ' run-12 "a b c"  d  e'
 command:          run-12
 argument:         "a b c"
 argument:         d
 argument:         e

 String To Parse:  ' run-13 "ab\"c"  "\\"  d'
 command:          run-13
 argument:         "ab\"c"
 argument:         "\\"
 argument:         d

 String To Parse:  ' run-14 a\\\b d"e f"g h'
 command:          run-14
 argument:         a\\\b
 argument:         d"e f"g
 argument:         h

 String To Parse:  ' run-15 a\\\"b c d'
 command:          run-15
 argument:         a\\\"b
 argument:         c
 argument:         d

 String To Parse:  ' run-16 a\\\\"b c" d e'
 command:          run-16
 argument:         a\\\\"b c"
 argument:         d
 argument:         e

 String To Parse:  ' run-17 "a b c""'
 command:          run-17
 argument:         "a b c""

 String To Parse:  ' run-18 """CallMeIshmael"""  b  c'
 command:          run-18
 argument:         """CallMeIshmael"""
 argument:         b
 argument:         c

 String To Parse:  ' run-19 """Call Me Ishmael"""'
 command:          run-19
 argument:         """Call
 argument:         Me
 argument:         Ishmael"""

 String To Parse:  ' run-20 """"Call Me Ishmael"" b c'
 command:          run-20
 argument:         """"Call Me Ishmael""
 argument:         b
 argument:         c

 String To Parse:  ' run-21 """CallMeIshmael"""'
 command:          run-21
 argument:         """CallMeIshmael"""

 String To Parse:  ' run-22 """Call Me Ishmael"""'
 command:          run-22
 argument:         """Call
 argument:         Me
 argument:         Ishmael"""

 String To Parse:  ' run-23 \"CallMeIshmael\"'
 command:          run-23
 argument:         \"CallMeIshmael\"

 String To Parse:  ' run-24 """"Call me Ishmael""""'
 command:          run-24
 argument:         """"Call me Ishmael""""

 String To Parse:  ' run-25 """"Call Me Ishmael""'
 command:          run-25
 argument:         """"Call Me Ishmael""

 String To Parse:  ' run-26 "\"Call Me Ishmael\""'
 command:          run-26
 argument:         "\"Call Me Ishmael\""
```

Comment: Thanks, this is an answer to mark as accepted, but the expressión is really long to understand what you've did at all, to be sure about what I'm using taking your regex please could you add to your answer a list of possibly false-positives that the the regex could produce and also a list of safe strings?. to understand me for example this argument: `Hotkey="Escape"` (notice that the `/` char is not written) will return an amount of 5 matches.

Comment: @ElektroStudios - I re-posted a fixup for most of MS command line arguments (although not all). Includes argument options `[[-/]val[=["dat"][dat][]]]` or stand alone `["val"]`.

Comment: Now it is perfect seems an universal regex, the previous regex only worked for this kind of arguments: "/Switch=value", thanks for your time, please feel free to update it if you can improve it more!

Comment: Sorry, fixed cut'n paste errors. This works now. Better to use this last update.

Comment: Could you fix the regex to be able to use quotes inside quotes? for example in this argument: `-Command="Dir /B "*.*""`

Comment: @ElektroStudios - Here you go.

Comment: is not working with this arguments: `"Console Application Template.vshost.exe" /Switch1=Value1 /Switch2="Value2"` the first quote is taken as a single argument

Comment: Thankyou so much, but I'm a little bit lost, in .NET which of the (new added) three regex of the comment lines I should use?

Comment: @ElektroStudios - We would use the second or third in code. We would use the first in _RegexFormat_ to format/modify then produce a second or third modified code-ready output. I started with _RegexFormat_ which produced all that you see in my post.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
 Dim DebugArguments As String =
    "HotkeyMaker.exe /Hotkey=""Escape"" /run=""c:\folder with spaces\notepad.exe"""
 Dim myMatches As MatchCollection
 Dim MyRegEx As New Regex("([^\/]+""|[^/\s]+)")

 myMatches = MyRegEx.Matches(DebugArguments)

 For Each match In myMatches
 MsgBox(match.Value)
 Next
```

Comment: Don't works, you've used the same (wrong) pattern that I've used in my question. What that pattern gets is this: `/run="c:\folder` but the expected is this: `/run="c:\folder with spaces\notepad.exe"`.

Comment: I did a little modification: `([^\/]+[^\s\/])` EDIT: But still don't working with this example: `"HotkeyMaker.exe /Hotkey=Escape /run=""c:\folder with spaces\notepad.exe"" wrong argument"`

Comment: Allthough, the / is missing from match 2 and 3.

Comment: I changed the code to a new regex, give it a try. worked for me!