# Optional regex character group

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to write a regex to validate some command line parameters, I have got it working but it doesn't seem very efficient, and with more to come I'd like to see if there's a way of grouping the parameter's together.

The command line has 3 optional parameters, `-h -s -r`, they might all be used, they might not be used at all.

The regex I have at the moment is

```
myapp.exe\s?(-h\s*)?\s?(-s\s*)\s?(-r\s*)?
```

Do I have to keep repeating `\s?(-x\s*)` for every parameter, or can I group them together? Something like `\s?(-h,-r,-s\s*)` would be very helpful!

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to have the same parameters repeating? E.g. `myapp.exe -h -h`

Comment: @Jerry No, they can only be used once, but in any order.

Comment: I think the only way to do this would be to generally parse the command line as Windows would, then check the arguments for validity. See this answer for details: [_Args_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303036/regular-expression-to-match-process-arguments/20303808#20303808)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like that:

```
myapp\.exe\s?(-[hsr]\s*)*
```

Don't forget to escape dots if you want the regex to match a literal dot.

`[ ... ]` is a character class and will match any one (or range if you define any) character inside.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/yX6zW2)

---

**EDIT:** To ensure that a flag is not duplicated, you can use a backreference and a negative lookahead, along with an end of line anchor:

```
myapp\.exe\s?(?:-([hsr])(?!.*\1)\s*)*$
```

`\1` will refer to whatever is captured in `([hsr])`

`(?! ... )` will negate the match if whatever inside is matched

`$` will ensure that the whole string is checked. You might want to remove that part if there is anything else coming after the string you provided in your question to make it properly match.

Comment: Brilliant, I knew it would be something simple, thanks Jerry.

Comment: I will accept in 6 minutes :) but how can I ensure they each only get used once?

Comment: @BaliC Sorry, I was afk for a meal. You can modify it a bit (it's a bit more complicated) and you get [this](http://regex101.com/r/gP8mW7).

Comment: Oh wow, I will have fun dissecting that! Thanks for your help :)